# Why this JavaScript code does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, input

This code should working, but I have no idea why it is not working at all.

HTML:

```
<p><input type="file" size="50"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
test = function() {
    console.dir(document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').value);
    var a = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').vaule;
    console.dir(a);
};
```

The first `console.dir` can successfully display the selected file filename

whereas I store it in `var a` is return undefined, whats happended?

fiddle: jsfiddle.net/eb5tuo7o

Comment: `vaule` != `value` - spelling mistake

Comment: ok..my fault..i cant notice that

Comment: Is this true we should answer such question and get vote for it?

Comment: @maytham, such questions will likely be deleted so upvote won't matter but it is good to make sure the OP got that typo first

Answer (score 3):

With the console log you're using `.value` but when you're storing it you've misspelled it as `.vaule`.

```
test = function() {
    console.dir(document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').value);
    var a = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').value;
    console.dir(a);
};
```

Comment: Well Noticied @Jesse

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "vaule"

You can access html elements value by using

```
 document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').value;
```

And if you are using jquery it's even simpler

```
  $("input[type=file]").val();
```